# Unable to create an .exe from Visual FoxPro

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I seem to be unable to create an executable file with **Visual FoxPro**. I have the following files which I believe can be opened in this discontinued program:

> X.cdx
>   X.~pv
>   X.DBF
>   X.PSQ
>   X.pv

I have been unsuccesfull in creating such a `.exe` and now the program only freezes when I open it. Would someone be able to help me out? Let me know if you can!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.PSQ is Adobe Premier, The DBF is database table, the CDX is an associated index file, no idea what the other two are. In summary then, you will not be building any type of Visual FoxPro executable with those.